# Add a comments section to post/pages on apostrophe cms

Tags: node.js, express, apostrophe-cms

I need to build a comments section on my apostrophe for users to be able and leave comments/feedback around content that someone will create in pages. That would require to create collections in the database as well as allow users to comment only but not to remove any the module/widget. Also, comments need to, of course, be linked to pages.

Not really sure, how I can approach this task. Whether, to build a separate microservice or a widget to handle this. I have read the tutorial for building a contact form in apostrophe, also tested. However, I don't really need to have an option on the Admin Bar as comments are linked to each page, I need the form to be static (don't want any users to remove them or add more than one on a single page), also want the comments to appear below the form once they have been submitted.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Thank you for your time.
Dcram

**EDIT**

Well, before I needed to do this for *pages* and I even managed to post the comments specific for each page where it should be. However, needed to make a few changes on my site and now this comment widget appears in **pieces** like blogposts! However, haven't being able to display the *specific comments for each piece*. Is there any way I can find the piece page url similar to `data.page._url` so that I can compare with the one attached to each comment?
Thanks!

Comment: @Ramirez, take a look into [disqus](https://disqus.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We almost always use Disqus for this purpose, but if you need a commenting functionality that is internal to your site, there is the [apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets) module that can be extended for this purpose.

You would definitely want the comments to be an instance of an `apostrophe-piece` in the docs collection, which would mean it would by default be included as an item in the admin bar. Easy enough to hide that, however.

Following this pattern would result in creating / configuring 3 project-level modules:

1. `comments` - extends `apostrophe-pieces`, defines the `comment` piece type
2. `comments-widgets` - extends `apostrophe-pieces-widgets`, a widget to display comments on a template (you could also hard code this behavior into a template instead of making it a widget)
3. `comments-submit-widgets` - extends `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets`, a widget to display the front-end form that users use to submit their comments

Answer (score 1):

Building this sort of functionality directly into a piece and its widget player is not too difficult, check out this project for more

https://github.com/stuartromanek/apostrophe-comment-system

Steps:

1. Checkout project / install / create user / get up and running
2. Create a Comment piece from the admin bad (Home Page Comments, for example)
3. Add the new piece to singleton widget on the homepage
4. Comment!

This code should give you a pretty clear guide for creating backend functionality that can be interacted with on the frontend.

Permissions for interacting with the widget itself should be managed through `apostrophe-permissions` http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/permissions.html